# TestNG call sequence of @AfterMethod and ITestListener#onFailure

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

Does anybody know what is called first if a test fails?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the annotation @AfterMethod then The annotated method will be run after each test method. if u use the alwaysRun option with this then it will be run even if one or more methods invoked previously failed or was skipped.

for more info visit http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: As far i can tell, @AfterMethod is always run, no matter if you use @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true) or not. 


What i *really* want to know is if i can savely assume that the sequence is

test fails => ItestListener#onFailue(TestResult) => @AfterMethod

or

test fails => @AfterMethod => ItestListener#onFailue(TestResult)

Answer (score 0):

@AfterMethod is called first in TestNG 5.11, but I'm not sure you can rely on this behaviour to remain the same in future TestNG versions.